# Is it possible to use Hyper-V to virtualize local developer machines?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

My job requires few local VMs for development. Right now I am trying to use Hyper-V on Windows 2008 R2. Main problem is connection to it.

1. Native connection is fast, but quite restrictive. You cannot copy/paste, client screen size do not work either and two monitors are not supported.
2. RDP connection is better in terms of features, but it is very slow, I can see even how console is redrawing.

Any other options? Or may be suggestions how to fix this issues? It looks that even Virtual Box works faster.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a hammer when you only need to screw something into a small hole.  If Virtual Box is faster I would use that.  This sounds like a performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have virtualised all our development boxes and use RDP to work on them from office, home and client sites.  We get the odd glitch but see no performance problems like you experience. There are some issues around the network card settings on Hyper-V (google TCPOffload I think) that you might be experiencing.